# gitk unknown color name "lime"

Tags: git, gitk

with git 2.13 gitk fails to start for an unknown color name "lime". Some old fix was to replace "lime" with a string, but there is no such "lime" anywhere in this latest code of git. How would you fix it?

> gitk --version
>
> ```
> Error in startup script: unknown color name "lime"
>
> (processing "-fore" option)
>
> invoked from within "$ctext tag conf m2 -fore [lindex $mergecolors 2]"
>
> (procedure "makewindow" line 347)
>
> invoked from within "makewindow"
>
> (file "/usr/bin/gitk" line 12548)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found out:
There is a config file for gitk (who set this???) just change all occurrences of "lime":

vi ~/.config/git/gitk

:%s/lime/"#99FF00"/g

Comment: I had a similar problem in Cygwin installed version of gitk. Had to edit ~/.config/git/gitk and comment out all lines (with #) that referred to System... color.